# Smooth only some edges in a mesh

Tags: smooth

I have a mesh (converted from a curve and extruded with solidify modifier).

[image]

As can be seen, the curved surface in the top show the flat faces.

I want to smooth this edges:

[image]

And keep sharp this edges:

[image]

If I apply a shade smooth globally in the mesh, I get this wrong result:

[image]

Even if I mark the edges as sharp, the result is the same. Is it possible smooth the edges in the curved surface and keep the other edges sharp?

[This is the Blender file](https://pasteall.org/blend/c10ce3732e7f44269ee38eb41a6e2bcb)

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you've shade smoothed, use the *Auto Smooth* option, it will determine under what angle the smooth will happen (the artefacts around the inner hole happen because Blender tries to smooth between these faces and the faces of the hole, which are 90°):

[image]

You can also select the faces you want, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to access the *Face* panel and choose *Shade Flat* (if you want to easily select all these faces, select one then press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (*Select Similar*) > *Normal*):

[image]

Also maybe you should simplify these faces with a <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*.